# Override spring resource value with classpath in test

Tags: java, spring

I wanna override the value of a resource in a test:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class MyExampleConfig {

  @Value("classpath:my-example-resource.yml")
  private Resource myExampleResource;

}
```

Does anybody know how I could override the value "classpath:my-example-resource.yml"in my test?

Comment: You can't override this - you've hardcoded it! You need to use a variable `${config.example.resource}` - set that in your `application.yaml`. Now - you can override that using [RichardK's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53653940/2071828).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running @SpringBootTest you can use this annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = {
        "key=value",
        "key=value"
})
```

They will override default ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a separate application.properties file for your test package under resources, and you can define a key value pair i.e :
`classpath=classpath:my-example-resource.yml` 
in this file and use in the code as follows

```
 @Value("${classpath}")
 private String classpath;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use create test configuration (`ApplicationTest`) with test `.properties` or `.yml` in test package and then use it in your tests

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationTest.class)
public class Test {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
      //some code
    }
}
```